# Argument of type 'int' is not iterable in python. please explain

Tags: python, graph

i have an adjacency list and i tried to iterate through the dictionary by passing the key as a parameter to the dictionary and then trying to find out whether a certain element was present in the dictionary(Adjacency list). But, this code is showing errors. can anyone tell me how to fix it?
Code:

```
count = 0
def BackAndForth(AList,end1,end2):
  global count
  if(end2 in AList[end1]):
    count+=1
  for i in AList[end1]:
    if(i!=end2):
      BackAndForth(AList[i],i,end2)

  return count



Alist = {
    0 :[2, 3, 6],
    1 :[3, 5 ,6] ,
    2 :[ 0 ,3 ,4],
    3 :[ 0 ,1 ,2, 4],
    4 : [2 ,3 ,5],
    5 :[ 1 ,4 ,6],
    6 :[ 0 ,1 ,5],
}
end1=0
end2=0
print(BackAndForth(Alist,end1,end2))
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I0ua.png)

Comment: You're trying to iterate over something that is an integer, but you need an iterable (list, tuple etc). This answer is both correct and useless. You should ask yourself why you have an integer in that place instead of an iterable or, if the integer is there correctly, why you're trying to iterate over it!

Answer (score 0):

Your function works fine on the first run, but note how you recursively pass `AList[I]` to `BackAndForth`. At that point you have an array, which sounds great, but you also have this in your code `end2 in AList[end1])` which will give you an int rather than the list you expected once it's invoked recursively. Fine, you decide to just pass AList. Now you have a different problem, it recurses infinitely. So now you have to tell it to stop when it finds a match. Try the following, it should work more like you expect it to:

```
count = 0
def BackAndForth(AList,end1,end2):
    global count
    if(end2 in AList[end1]):
        count+=1
        return count
    for i in AList[end1]:
        if(i!=end2):
            BackAndForth(AList,i,end2)
            
    return count

Alist = {
        0 :[2, 3, 6],
        1 :[3, 5 ,6] ,
        2 :[ 0 ,3 ,4],
        3 :[ 0 ,1 ,2, 4],
        4 : [2 ,3 ,5],
        5 :[ 1 ,4 ,6],
        6 :[ 0 ,1 ,5],
}
end1=0
end2=0
print(BackAndForth(Alist,end1,end2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dude, for your explanation. As u said the function recurses infinitely. After that, i tried to fix it by adding a visited dictionary which has nodes as the keys and values as either true or false depending on the status whether its visited or not. I even added the condition on the if statement(to check if a node is not visited and then proceed). But, still it recurses infinitely.Any tips on how to stop this?

```
count = 0
def BackAndForth(AList,end1,end2):
  global count
  visited={}
  for i in AList.keys():
    visited[i] = False
  print(AList[end1])
  visited[end1] = True
  if(end2 in AList[end1]):
    count+=1
  for i in AList[end1]:
    if(i!=end2 and not visited[i]):
      visited[i] = True
      BackAndForth(AList,i,end2)
  


  return count
```